# Doctrine 2 : Custom repositories and inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, repository, customization

Hello Stack Overflowers,

Working with Doctrine 2, I encounter some troubles regarding custom repositories and inheritance.

Long story short, I want to make that kind of structure :

- BaseEntityRepository : contains generic methods such as findByXXX() based on called class name
- SomeEntityRepository : contains specific methods related to the entity type

The code for those classes looks like this :

BaseEntityRepository :

```
namespace model\repositories;

use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class BaseEntityRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findByID($id) {
        $result = null;

        try {
            $dql = "SELECT a FROM " . get_called_class() . " a WHERE a.id = :id";
            $query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
            $query->setParameter("id", $id);
            $result = $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

SomeEntityRepository :

```
namespace model\repositories;

class SomeEntityRepository extends BaseEntityRepository {

}
```

My test sample code :

```
$repo = $em->getRepository("model\\entities\\SomeEntity");
$result = $repo->findByID($id);
```

With this code, I expect `$repo` to have access to the `findByID($id)` method by inheritance from `BaseEntityRepository`. Of course, the `repositoryClass` annotation for `SomeEntity` targets `SomeEntityRepository`. On the contrary, `BaseEntityRepository` is NOT targeted as a standalone repository class.

The thing is, all I get is an exception :

> Class "model\repositories\SomeEntityRepository" sub class of
>   "model\repositories\BaseEntityRepository" is not a valid entity or
>   mapped super class.

I can't, for the sake of me, figure out what's wrong in this code. Maybe I missed something but my research towards inheritance in repositories did not bring any satisfying results. I guess there is some kind of restriction on repositories such as for them to work properly, all should be targeted as repositoryClass at least once or something like that, but that doesn't please me.

If you have any kind of insight, piece of advice or bits of solution, I'm all ears! Thanks again.

Comment: Drop the leading back slash from use \Doctrine... I suspect your problem is actually in your dql query.  Trace through it.

Comment: Dropping the back slash doesn't change anything. But, as you suspected, the problem is indeed coming from the query. I used `get_called_class()` to actually get the entity name but the way I implemented the structure this could never happen. I'll think on another way, but the problem was indeed coming from the DQL query. Didn't think it could come from that. May I ask you to change your comment to an answer so I can actually select it as correct? Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with get_called_class which is not going to do what you want.

Use the doctrine query builder.  That eliminates the need to know the specific entity class.

Search for: Querying for Objects Using Doctrine's Query Builder

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this post, here is the solution I used :

I simply replaced the wrong `get_called_class()` by `$this->_entityName`, where `_entityName` is available through Doctrine's EntityRepository since my class extends it. Works like a charm, thanks again!

Comment: Great that you got it working but do take a look at using the query builder when you have time.  I'm assuming that you plan on eventually having more advanced queries.  The query builder will save you a lot of trouble.