# Doctrine: Custom repository method with inheritable entity

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine, repository

I have a base entity class called `User`, which has 3 possible different child-classes `Employee`, `Customer` and `Student`. This is implemented with a single table inheritance.

The base class `User` has two fields called `name`and `prename`, which all the child classes inherit.

Now my problem: I have a custom repository called `UserRepository` with the method `findByFullTextSearch(string $searchterm): User[]` in which I implemented a somewhat Full-Text-Search on those two fields to fit my needs (unfortunately, I do not have the possibility to use DoctrineExtensions for this project to implement the MySQL function `FIND_IN_SET` or an actual Full-Text-Search).

Is there any possibility for me to only write this method once in `UserRepository`, so when I use `$doctrine->getRepository(Student::class)->findByFullTextSearch('john doe');` I only get results fitting to the Repository i called it from?

### My workarounds so far:

- Implement all repository classes, pass `get_called_class()` or `$this->_entityName` to parent class.
- Call the base repository class and pass the child entity class as parameter to `findByFullTextSearch`

Here I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781592/doctrine-2-custom-repositories-and-inheritance), but not quite the same.

Is there a better solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by simply adding the base class as repository for each child entity:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UserBundle\Entity\Customer.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class Customer extends User
{
    // ...
```

This way I wont need empty child repositories just for doctrine to find a possible entry point.